# Connecting to Couchbase Server using C SDK

Tags: c, couchbase

I've been trying to connect to a Couchbase. cluster using the C SDK but have been getting this error :

```
  "_lcb_createopts_connstr", referenced from:
      _main in minimal.c.o
  "_lcb_createopts_create", referenced from:
      _main in minimal.c.o
  "_lcb_createopts_credentials", referenced from:
      _main in minimal.c.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

OS : macOS Big Sur.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Could you add to the question the code returning that error? Do not forget to always include a minimal, reproducible example of your code as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs during the linking phase. Ensure that you have properly configure your linker to use the `libcouchbase`.